# Fetch all nested content files and group them by directories in Nuxt content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm having this list of blogposts called `articles`
that I call from the content folder.

```js
  async asyncData ({ $content }) {
    const articles = await $content('', { deep: true })
      //  .where({ cat: 'A' })
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug', 'cat'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return { articles }
  }
```

This fetches all of my articles and returns a list of them.

[image]

Now, I would like to populate my different categories in my website following this structure :

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="article in articles" :key="article">
      {{ article.title }}
    </div>
    <pre> {{ articles }}</pre>

    <div v-for="accordion in accordions" :key="accordion.title" class="l">
      <Item>
        <template #title>
          {{ accordion.title }}
        </template>

        <template #content>
          <div> {{ accordion.text }}</div>
        </template>
      </Item>
    </div>
    <!-- here goes R -->
    <div class="r" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Item from '../components/List-item.vue'
export default {
  components: { Item },
  async asyncData ({ $content }) {
    const articles = await $content('', { deep: true })
      //  .where({ cat: 'A' })
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug', 'cat'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return { articles }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      accordions: [
        {
          title: 'A',
          text: 'Projects from content/A'
        },
        {
          title: 'B',
          text: 'Projects from content/B'
        },
        {
          title: 'C',
          text: 'Projects from content/C'
        }
      ]
}
</script>
```

It's using slots from a componenent :

```html
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div
      :class="{ active: isActive }"
      @click="toggle"
    >
      <a class="title">
        <slot name="title" />
      </a>

      <div v-show="show" :class="{ active: isActive }" class="content">
        <slot name="content" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've nested my array into a v-for, but I don't know how to dynamically group that array by URL or by category.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Just a tip. Use v-if instead v-show because v-show renders inactive post. But if you care about performance  filter your active post before render the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would achieve that while keeping it fully dynamic and less error prone.

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="(filteredArticles, categoryKey) in groupedCategories" :key="categoryKey">
      <h2>{{ categoryKey }}</h2>
      <list-item v-for="article in filteredArticles" :key="article.slug">
        <template #title>
          {{ article.title }}
        </template>
        <template #content>
          <div> {{ article.description }}</div>
        </template>
        <br>
      </list-item>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData ({ $content }) {
    const articles = await $content('', { deep: true })
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug', 'cat', 'dir'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return { articles }
  },
  computed: {
    groupedCategories () {
      return this.articles.reduce((finalObject, obj) => {
        const directory = obj.dir
        finalObject[directory] ?? (finalObject[directory] = [])
        finalObject[directory].push(obj)
        return finalObject
      }, {})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The `.only(['dir'])` gives us all the directories aka `/A`, `/B` etc, so that it's fully dynamic and not relying on OP's needing to remember to put a `cat` in the `.md` file.
It is generated for any kind of content as [shown here](https://content.nuxtjs.org/v1/getting-started/writing#example-4) and avoids us some ugly and complex regex subgroups.

Then we're [using a `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#grouping_objects_by_a_property) to properly group all the articles depending on their respective directories, filtering on `dir` as explained before.

The [Logical Nullish Assignment operator](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/operator-lookup?match=logical-nullish-assignment) in the documentation didn't worked for me for some reason, hence I replaced it with it's alternative aka `finalObject[directory] ?? (finalObject[directory] = [])` to basically set a new array in case of a non-existing key.
The idea is to get an **object** with a key for each directory, itself containing an **array** of all the articles.

This is how it looks locally + Vue devtools.

[image]

A github repo can be found here: https://github.com/kissu/AppPortfolio
Useful since it's a bit cumbersome to mock all kind of `.md` files.
A deployed version can be found here: https://papaya-truffle-df823c.netlify.app/

Answer (score 3):

If the intent is to see the list of articles queried in an accordion that divides them by "cat", you can augment the accordion data structure in data to include the articles found in the query...

```
async asyncData ({ $content }) {
  const articles = await $content('', { deep: true })
    .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug', 'cat'])
    .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
    .fetch()

  // set accordions as an array of grouped articles
  const groups = articles.reduce((acc, article) => {
    if (!acc[article.cat]) acc[article.cat] = { 
      title: article.cat,
      text: `Articles about ${article.cat}`,
      articles: []  // <-- gather the articles for this cat here
    };
    acc[article.cat].articles.push(article);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  this.accordions = Object.values(groups);
}
```

The markup should iterate the `accordion` in data (which are really categories), and then nest iteration of the articles in each category...

```
<div v-for="accordion in accordions" :key="accordion.title" class="l">
  <Item>
    <template #title>
      {{ accordion.title }}
    </template>

    <template #content>
      <div> {{ accordion.text }}</div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(article, i) in accordion.articles" :key="i">
          {{article.title}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </Item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional queries with `@nuxt-content` module:

```js
{
  async asyncData ({ $content }) {
    const articlesC = await $content('', { deep: true })
      .where({ cat: { $contains: 'C' } })
      // Or .where({ cat: { $eq: 'C' } })
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug', 'cat'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return { articles }
  }
}
```

And the create an array for each category.

If you do not want to create a query for each category you can use the `Array.filter` (or `Array.reduce`) method to group your articles big query.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that filtering an array is more what I’m looking for.

Comment: Fetching several times is not the way to go indeed, quite making the same query X times.